# VueJS Blank Page

Tags: vue.js

I am currently trying to learn VueJS and I am having this issue where the page is just blank. I can't figure out why this is not working. It was all working yesterday but after I restarted my PC the page is just blank.

Here are my files:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**src/main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

createApp(App).mount('#app')
```

**src/App.vue**

```
<template>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: 'App'
  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: Your browser console should output an error message. Can you post that as well?

Comment: How are you running this? Becuase you need a development server to do so…